# Java unbounded counted semaphore?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I need to provide a method that blocks until all outstanding work in a BlockingQueue has been processed.

I was thinking I could handle this with a counted semaphore which would start at 0 and decrement as items are added to the queue and increment as they are completed. finish() would just acquire the semaphore, release it again and leave.

I could perhaps call reducePermits(). Does this work if permit count is already < 0? It's protected, so I would need to extend the Semaphore class to make it work.

My second best idea is to check the contents of the queue in a loop and sleep 100ms or so between checks. It works but seems kludgey.

Does this make sense? Anybody have an easier / cleaner way to suggest?

TIA,
    - Tim.

```
public MyClass {
  public class MySemaphore extends Semaphore {
    public void seize() {
      reducePermits(1);
    }
  }
  private MySemaphore allDone = new MySemaphore();
  void startSomething() {
    allDone.seize();
  }
  void finishSomething() {
    allDone.release();
  }
  void finish() {
    allDone.acquire();
    allDone.release();
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't know what problem you are trying to solve, but have a look if CompletionService works for you (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html).

Comment: yup, or maybe a `CountdownLatch` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html depending on what you're trying to do.  (Explain more about the use case?)

Comment: Thanks, I thought of those too, but they didn't quite work for me:

CompletionService and Future<T> feel to me like they are trying to handle a bunch of separate threads which exit. I have a single thread processing a batch of work which does not exit.

CountdownLatch assumes a known number of elements you count down from. I need to wait for an arbitrary number of items and unbock when all are done.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, the more I realize I'm having one thread try to tell when another one is done. I should just ask the worker thread to wrap things up (add a flag), and have the worker signal when he's all done via a semaphore. The problem becomes easy with a better division of labor.

Answer (score 2):

You could drain the queue by calling [`drainTo(collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo%28java.util.Collection%29), then invoke processing yourself on all items (possibly via Futures etc), then your final processing.

Comment: This makes sense. The only reason I didn't go this way already is that the concurrency issues make me nervous. If problems do arise, they will be ugly to debug. I guess I'm just being paranoid. There shouldn't be any concurrency issues between the various methods of LinkedBlockingQueue, should there?

Comment: Ok, after some thought, I see why this doesn't work for me. In the actual use case, processing for each item of the queue involves writing results out to an output stream. Each item has to be fully processed before the next can start, so I can't just grab items from the queue while the worker thread is active and start working on them in a separate thread. Good answer, I just didn't specify this in the question.

Comment: If you have to process them sequentially, have only one worker thread doing the processing.

Comment: Yes, the problem at hand is detecting when that thread has finished the work on hand. My silliness was in trying to do that from the requesting thread rather than asking the worker to notify of completion.